# Referencing a workbook file path found in another sub (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I am running into this issue where I import and open a workbook in the first sub but want to reference it in the second but I'm not sure how. Right now it is a static name (I denoted the line with a few single quotes).

I tried referencing my variable "filename" but because it has to be sheet within the workbook I'm not positive how to do that. Thank you in advance!

```
Sub Procedure1()
    Dim Filt As String
    Dim filterindex As Integer
    Dim title As String
    Dim filename As Variant


    Filt = "Comma Seperated Files (*.csv),*.csv"    
    filterindex = 1


    title = "Select a File to Import"

    filename = Application.GetOpenFilename _
        (FileFilter:=Filt, _
        filterindex:=filterindex, _
        title:=title)


    If filename = False Then
        MsgBox "No file was selected"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Workbooks.Open filename
End Sub

Sub Procedure2()
    Dim CurrentWS As Worksheet
    Set CurrentWS = ActiveSheet

    Dim SourceWS As Worksheet
    Set SourceWS = Workbooks("cedar.csv").Worksheets(1)''''''''''''''''''''''
    Dim SourceHeaderRow As Integer: SourceHeaderRow = 1
    Dim SourceCell As Range

    Dim TargetWS As Worksheet
    Set TargetWS = Workbooks("Prototype.xlsm").Worksheets(1)
    Dim TargetHeader As Range
    Set TargetHeader = TargetWS.Range("A1:AX1")

    Dim RealLastRow As Long
    Dim SourceCol As Integer


    SourceWS.Activate
    For Each Cell In TargetHeader
        If Cell.Value <> "" Then
            Set SourceCell = Rows(SourceHeaderRow).Find _
                (Cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            If Not SourceCell Is Nothing Then
                SourceCol = SourceCell.Column
                RealLastRow = Columns(SourceCol).Find("*", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
                If RealLastRow > SourceHeaderRow Then
                    Range(Cells(SourceHeaderRow + 1, SourceCol), Cells(RealLastRow, _
                        SourceCol)).Copy
                    TargetWS.Cells(2, Cell.Column).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next

    CurrentWS.Activate
    Workbooks("Prototype.xlsm").Sheets(1).Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you would pass the workbook as an argument to the second Sub:

```
Sub One()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(somePath)
    Two wb
End sub

Sub Two(wb As Workbook)
    With wb.sheets(1)
        'work with sheet
    End with
End sub
```

EDIT:  I notice you don't actually call `Two` from `One`, so an alternative (but not as robust) way might be:

```
Dim wb As Workbook 'Global variable

Sub One()
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(somePath)
End sub

Sub Two()
    With wb.sheets(1) 'use the global variable
        'work with sheet
    End with
End sub
```